# Verify proof about elementary claim on convex set and separating hyperplane

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, hilbert-spaces, convex-geometry

> *Question:*
> Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a non-empty convex set and $x_0$ in $C$ closed ($x_0 \in \overline{C}$) but $x_0 \notin int(C)$. Then there exists $a \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \}$ s.t. $\forall x \in C$ it is true that $a\cdot x_0 \geq a\cdot x$

For my answer I had the idea to use the [hyperplane separation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperplane_separation_theorem), but we can't use it directly as $\mathbb{R}^n \setminus C $ is not a convex set. So first I need to build a disjoint to $C$ nonempty set contening $x_0$. And here is my problem as I don't succeed to build clearly one of this type of set like a simple segment for exemple (or to show that those type sets exist).

*Here my best attempt for the moment.*

- 1/Lets suppose by absurd that it doesn't exists a segment $$S=\left \{ \lambda x_0 +(1-\lambda)y_0 | \lambda \in \left [ 0;1 \right ] \right \}$$ with $y_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \left \{ C \right \}$ that has none of his elements/points in $C$. This will mean that at least for one $\lambda'$ we have that $\lambda' x_0 +(1-\lambda')y_0 \in C$.
  On the other hand $\exists x'' \in int(C)$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x_0=x'' \alpha$.
  And as $x'', x' \in C$ the segment that connect them must to be in $C$ too. But in such a case this segment will contain $x_0$! That means $x_0 \in C$.
- 2/By hyperplane separation theorem we have that $\forall s \in S$ and $\forall c \in C, \exists \beta \in \mathbb{R},a \in \mathbb{R}^n \setminus \left \{ 0 \right \} $ s.t. it is verify: $<a|s> \geq \beta \geq <a|c>$. And if it is true $\forall s \in S$ it is in particular true for $s=x_0$

Q.E.D.

Is is it correct?
In all the case if any one as a better solution to this question I will be happy to read it.
Thank you.

Comment: The 'solution-verification' tag description reads: "For posts looking for feedback or verification of a proposed solution. "Is my proof correct?" is off topic (too broad, missing context). Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof that is in doubt, and why so. This should not be the only tag for a question, and should not be used to circumvent site policies regarding duplicate questions." Your post is "Is my proof correct?" and therefore is off topic.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I don't understand your remark as I ve clearly wrote where were my doubt? Especially is the closed subset that I ve buildt from $x_0$ is correct? And after did I used correctly the Hyperplan separation theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two sets that you separate are $int(C)$ and $\{x_0\}$. Both are convex and disjoint, so you find a supporting hyperplane that has $a^Tx_0\ge m$ and $a^Tx<0$ for all $x\in C$.

---

To your attempt, in 1/ the existence of $x''$ is not guaranteed, as the ray connecting $x_0$ to the origin can be tangent to the convex set, touching it in just the point $x_0$. 2/ is true but as said, you do not need the segment outside $C$, the point set  $\{x_0\}$ in itself is already convex.

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer. Is this that simple? And in all the case is my answer correct?

Comment: The heavy lifting happens in the hyperplane separation theorem. You would have to check if your version would have a problem if the distance between the convex sets is zero. Otherwise yes, use that the point is a boundary point and thus has point of $C$ and points of the complement arbitrarily close-by.

Comment: Thank, I have a very simple question. From the question, we can't conclude that $C$ is an open (and of course not a closed set). And yet we can use the hyperplane separation theorem with $C$ and $x_0$. Is it correct?

Comment: In 2/ you find a plane that separates $S$ and $C$. But $S$ also contains the boundary point $x_0$. So if you see no problem in your proposal, then $S$ can also be reduced to a single point.

Comment: Thank for your remark. Why do you say that the existence of $x''$ as the ray connecting $x0$ to the origin can be tangent to the convex set?
 But yet $x_0$ is colinear with at least one vector in $C$ ? I think it is because i haven't be very clear. You can take i.e points $a,b\in C$ such that $\lambda \overrightarrow{ab}= \overrightarrow{ax_0}$ as we are in$\mathbb{R}^n$. (I hope I am clear)

Comment: And again this simple question.From the question, we can't conclude that $C$ is an open set (and of course not a closed set). And yet we can use the hyperplane separation theorem with $C$ and $x0$. Is it correct?

Comment: It was nowhere stated that the origin is an inner point of $C$. // $int(C)$ is also a convex set.

Comment: I didn't argue that. Lets take for exemple a circle=C not center on the origine in $R^2$ such that $x_0$ is tangente as you said. Yet there exist a vector $\underset{ab}{\rightarrow}$ tottaly in the circle ($a, b \in$ this circle s.t. we can multiply it by a scalar and we get $\underset{ax_0}{\rightarrow}$. In other words: $\underset{ab}{\rightarrow} \lambda=\underset{ax_0}{\rightarrow}$. I hope I am clear enough as it is quiet difficult to explain it.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean. However this is not what you wrote in the question. There $x''$ is an interior point and you claim that for some number $x_0=\alpha x''$.

Comment: thank you so this my fault, I ven't been clear enough. But in such a case does it make my proof correct?